# Difference between Blazor project types in vs2019

Tags: blazor

In vs2019 with Blazor 0.9 there are two types of Blazor project. One is for a stand-alone project type and the other is for a .NET core hosted project.

I presume that the .NET core hosted project means that it has to be run from a .NET Core supported server but is still executed client-side? Is that correct? Or is this a replacement term for Razor Components?

Does the standalone project type mean that I can host a blazor app on any server? i.e. can I host a Blazor app on stock-standard Apache? Are there any sample projects of walkthroughs showing how to do this?

My particular need is that I need to supply a server-agnostic client for my REST api.

Answer (score 2):

The stand-alone Blazor template will scaffold a Blazor project which you can publish to any server, there is no requirement for .NET Core on the server. When you publish this template the result is static files. This project type can therefor be hosted pretty much anywhere, GitHub pages, Netlify, Azure blob storage etc... I've written a post covering deploying to Azure blob storage [here](https://chrissainty.com/deploying-blazor-apps-using-azure-pipelines/).

The hosted Blazor template will scaffold a solution with a Blazor project and a ASP.NET Core WebAPI project which is setup to serve the Blazor app. This project requires .NET Core on the server.

Both of these templates use client-side Blazor not server-side Blazor (what was briefly known as Razor Components).

From what you've said you would need the stand-alone Blazor template.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i'm just following this up. Vis Studio community in 2020 now seems to have one blazor framework which is the app.

This follows up from what Chris said, they're merging all the different types of blazor framework into one project file that can then be ported to whatever "flavor" of development you need.

there are still razor templates in there, but given what MS are doing, it seems everything will be one standardised template in the near future.